# update twitter bootstrap hidden tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap 2.3 in my project for developing a tab based web application.

As is the norm, at any given time only one tab is active and all the others are hidden, I control this behavior through javascript.

However , I have a situation where I want to update the html content in one of the tabs which is hidden so that later when it is shown it displays the modified content. However I found that updating the content of a hidden tab does not work unless I mark it for updating and then update us just after it is made visible.

I want to know if such a behavior can be achieved in bootstrap or by using some additional javascript/css logic such that hidden tabs can be updated and later on when they are enabled, then their content immediately shows up without delay.

Thanks

Comment: You can updated hidden tab content using ajax.

Comment: I have tried exactly the same thing. But the updated content does not show up when the tab becomes active.

Comment: Can you post your code here.